# How to validate date format in textbox using ASP.NET c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

This is my code

WebForm1.aspx:-

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="datetime.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" href="Content/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txtDate").datepicker();
        });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate" ErrorMessage="enter valid date" SetFocusOnError="False" ValidationExpression="^([0]?[0-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code i have a textbox , when user click on textbox it opens calender for date selection. When user not select data from calender , user write date manually on textfield how to validate if user enter wrong format. I tried write regularexpression when i use regularexpression calender not showing but validation worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using the JQuery UI datepicker, I would suggest use JQuery Validation rather than the c# validation. the below should work

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker();

$("#txtDate").blur(function(){
        val = $(this).val();
        val1 = Date.parse(val);
        if (isNaN(val1)==true && val!==''){
           alert("error")
        }
        else{
           console.log(val1);
        }
});
```

Add a HTML

tag or something next to text box and if validation fails set the message to your error message. like `<p id="myp"> </p>` and then edit the above like

```
if (isNaN(val1)==true && val!==''){
               $("p#myp").text('Date is not valid');
            }
```

The answer is just a pointer in the right direction, you can use this technique to customise your solution.

Comment: I want to show validation like beside of my textbox like asp.net validations.

Comment: First time error will be shown if i enter wrong date , but that error will not clear if i enter valid date also

Comment: As I mentioned, the answer is just a pointer, you can clear the message if date is valid..... try a few things